# Pass "generic" JsonProvider to function in F#

Tags: f#, type-providers

I have two JsonProvider types:

```
type Provider1 = JsonProvider<"""{structure}""">
type Provider2 = JsonProvider<"""{}structure2""">
```

I'd like to have a function, that can accept any of these and parse json using provided JsonProvider, something like this:(pseudo code, not compiling)

```
let parseUsingSpecificProvider json (provider : JsonProvider<GENERIC>) =
    provider.Parse json
```

Answer (score 2):

You can define an inline function with Statically Resolved Type Parameters (SRTPs):

```
let inline parseUsingSpecificProvider json (provider:^T) =
    (^T : (static member Parse : string -> _) json) 

// tests
#r @"packages\FSharp.Data\lib\net40\FSharp.Data.dll"
open FSharp.Data

type Provider1 = JsonProvider<""" { "name":"John"           } """>
type Provider2 = JsonProvider<""" { "name":"John", "age":94 } """>

let x = parseUsingSpecificProvider  (""" { "name":"Tomas", "age":4 } """) Unchecked.defaultof<Provider1>
let y = parseUsingSpecificProvider  (""" { "name":"Tomas", "age":4 } """) Unchecked.defaultof<Provider2>
```

So it will work with any type that has the static method `Parse` accepting a string as input.

Answer (score 0):

In functional programming it is common to replace 'single function interfaces' with the function itself. I.e. instead of passing in a parser having a `Parse` method, just use the `Parse` function as a first class value:

```
#r @"packages\FSharp.Data\lib\net40\FSharp.Data.dll"
open FSharp.Data

type Provider1 = JsonProvider<""" { "name":"John"           } """>
type Provider2 = JsonProvider<""" { "name":"John", "age":94 } """>

let parse parseFn json =
    parseFn json

let p1 = parse Provider1.Parse """{ "name": "Not John" }"""
let p2 = parse Provider2.Parse """{ "name": "Not John either", "age": 12 }"""
```

If you need several methods of the provided type, you could use e.g. a record containing all necessary data:

```
type Parser<'b> = {
    Parse : string -> 'b
    GetSample : unit -> 'b
}

let parseUsing parser text =
    printfn "Parsing things like %A" <| parser.GetSample()
    parser.Parse text

let parser1 = { Parse = Provider1.Parse; GetSample = Provider1.GetSample }
let parser2 = { Parse = Provider2.Parse; GetSample = Provider2.GetSample }

let p1' = parseUsing parser1 """{ "name": "Not John" }"""
let p2' = parseUsing parser2 """{ "name": "Not John either", "age": 12 }"""
```

While SRTPs are powerful (and cool), their usage should be limited. Overuse slows down the compiler and makes code harder to understand.